# Div slideup and show another div in its place

Tags: jquery, css

I am attempting to create an effect on my website that once you hover over a box, that div slides up to reveal another div containing more details. This is simular to how the following websites do this...

> http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php
>   http://plus.google.com/pages/create

Facebook - on clicking a category
Google+ - upon hovering over a category (how i would like my website to function)

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be amazing, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [$.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) along with some CSS to achieve this effect like this:

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/6dnRy/

**CSS**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;   
    top: 0;
}

.itemTop {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #ccc;   
}

.itemBottom {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #fff000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="itemTop">Top</div>
        <div class="itemBottom">Bottom</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="itemTop">Top</div>
        <div class="itemBottom">Bottom</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
/**    
 * $.on() is jQuery 1.7+
 * use $('.container').click(function(e){... for < 1.7
 */
$(document).on('click', '.container', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Action
    $('.inner').animate({top:0}, 'linear'); // Reset Other Containers
    $('.inner', this).animate({top:-250}, 'linear'); // Animate Clicked Container
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: @nblackburn NP; Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to place two elements on top of each other and then use JavaScript to animate the top element out of the way. There are really a lot of different methods so it's all about finding the effect you want.

Here is a jsfiddle for sliding one element on top of another: http://jsfiddle.net/PdZKP/

JS

```
$('#front').on('mouseenter', function () {//where front is the element on top
    $(this).slideUp();
}).on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).slideDown();
});
```

CSS

```
#back {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 0;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 100px;
    height     : 100px;
    background : #000;
    z-index    : 1;
}
#front{
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 0;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 100px;
    height     : 100px;
    background : #abc;
    z-index    : 2;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="back"></div>
<div id="front"></div>
```

I updated the jsfiddle for a slightly different animation style: http://jsfiddle.net/PdZKP/1/ (I think this is what you're looking for)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.lotusmarketing.ca/js/jsprite/

This could help you, example 1b.